# How to use webpack.config.js custom configuration?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a react project with webpack with a webpack.config.js file like this

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

const config = {
  serverBaseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000',
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  entry:  __dirname + "/app/App.js",
  output: {
    path: "./public/js/",
    publicPath: "/js/",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: "babel",
      query: {
        presets: ["es2015","react","stage-0"]
      }
    }]
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 8008,
    contentBase: "./public",
    colors: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    inline: true
  },
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  config.serverBaseUrl = 'http://api.domain.com';
  config.devtool = false;
  config.plugins = [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({comments: false}),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')}
    })
  ];
};

module.exports = config;
```

I would like to use `config.serverBaseUrl` in another js file? What should I do?

Can I do

`const config = require('./webpack.config.js')`

and use the config like this

`config.serverBaseUrl`

**UPDATE**:

if I use  `const= require('config')` in another file
I got this error

```
ERROR in ./app/components/ComponentBase.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'config' in /Users/username/data/projects/bwe_web/app/components
 @ ./app/components/ComponentBase.js 33:13-30
```

Comment: Looks like you're already exporting config, why not just require config?

Comment: Since yo have already exported `config`, I believe you can get it in any other file using `config.serverBaseUrl` if you have required it.

Comment: @DylanWright Please see my update. I got an error of `Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'config'`

Comment: @MamdohSaraireh Please see my update . I got an error of `Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'config'`

Comment: You can't use `require('config')` because you have no file named `config.js`

Comment: @J.Titus how do I require?

Comment: Did you try `require('webpack.config')`? What was the result?

Comment: @J.Titus  `ERROR in ./app/actions/AppActions.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'webpack.config' in /Users/name/data/projects/bwe_web/app/actions
 @ ./app/actions/AppActions.js 19:13-38`

Comment: Make sure the path is correct, I do not think you have the webpack config file in the actions directory.

Answer (score 0):

ICN,
To go along with J. Titus statement, you probably should just create another JavaScript class called say Environment.js and export it and use the settings from there.  At the top of your JS class you can require Environment.js and then just pull in the values.  Keep your webpack config your web.pack config.

```
'use strict'
var EnvironmentSettings = function(){
   var serverBaseUrl = 'http://api.domain.com';
};

module.exports.EnvironmentSettings = EnvironmentSettings;
```

Then for any implementation that you need or say want to implement/initialize, you'd just require it at the top of the JavaScript Class.

```
const envSettings = require('EnvironmentSettings');
var api = envSettings.serverBaseUrl
```

You should familiarize yourself with some kind of JS Patterns as well.  Prototype Pattern, Revealing Prototype Pattern and this will help with your education of including external classes.